# How do I pass argument from an activity to another in Workflow 4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have created an Activity (CodeActivity) that retrieves the temperature where I live.
I wan't to add that activity to a workflow and connect it to an if statement/activity that can based on my temperature outargument do different things.
But I can't seem to find how to access the outargument from my temperature-activity.

This is my first Windows Workflow 4 project so perhaps I'm attacking this in the wrong way.
I have:

```
public OutArgument<decimal> Degrees { get; set; }
```

But how do I access it? I have found tutorials how to get the data when running the activity (only one) but not as part of a workflow.
Hope my question makes sence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add à Variable to the worflow and bind the OutArgument from your CodeActivity to the variable. Next you can use the variable in the If activity.

Comment: I know how to create a varible but not how to bind it to the outArgument?

/Jimmy

Comment: Nevermind :P I figured it out, it was to simple I never even considered it to be that simple.
Just set Your OutArgument to the variable name in the properies for your Activity.

Comment: Yep, that is all there is to it :-D